# Unable to connect to Rails development address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, http

I am trying to run a Rails application. I am very new to this so I might have missed something obvious. I have Windows. I have installed Ruby using the Rails Installer for Windows. I am in the command prompt.

```
rails new application
cd application directory
rails server
```

It then starts the server but I cannot access the http address at 0.0.0.0:3000. I cannot type anything further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is a little misleading. Open your browser, and go to

```
localhost:3000
```

This should get you to the Rails default page. In case this doesn't work, the console output should give you more information (e.g. any application errors that occur when you request the page).

If you ever switch decide to switch to production mode and deploy on a real server that is directly connected to the internet, don't trust the IP address given to you by the `rails server` command either — always use your outbound IP address.